# Deploy Angular 4 front-end, .Net Web Api back-end on IIS upon same website 404 on refresh

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router, iis-express

I have a web application composed by an Angular 4 front-end client-side code who calls a back-end services part written in ASP.NET WebAPi. I have deployed my web application on IIS v10 on the same web site but on refresh i get 404 not found exception.

So now I have one website in the IIS's with two subdirectories called wwwroot who contains Angular production code and a bin folder for WebApi release code.
The site works well unless i press the browser's refresh button where I take 404 Exception. I have found many solution on the Internet but no one works.
I tryed to install IIS's urlrewrite component and added this rewrite rule in my Web.config file located in the root folder:

```xml
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

but I got this errors:
localhost/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8084/styles.a41bc47d7e564e63171c.bundle.css".
inline.f6f68ecaf0de3791ceeb.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
polyfills.0eff33741bac279a3ec4.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
vendor.1780747a4ea2f98b2a5b.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.2ee824fa31f5e7f44a12.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
How can I solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. 
I put the WebApi and Angular app files in the same folder on IIS
So the only problem you need to fix is the 404 of the api to redirect it to the Angular entry point, in my case is "/" becase I have Index.html on the root folder

In web.config remove the rewrite section and add this under system.webServer:

```
<system.webServer>

  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
   <clear />
   <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

This works like a charm. 
Angular routes will handle the url properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The above error comes when their is no handling of the requested css and js file and server returns status code 200 with no error. But the returned file is contains the error as an HTML text

So here above when you check the response in the chrome in the network tab you will find

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ...>
   <html>
     ...
 Some html error in side this 
</body></html>
```

> We have solved this problem by disabling the **IPv6** check policy.